Will there be Winter Bash 2020 competition on Bricks.SE?
Last year we had Winter Bash 2019 competition. While you could win some LEGO prizes last year it was quite fun to participate on its own. Are we going to have something like that this Winter Bash period as well?

Thanks for the reminder. I had prepared this beforehand, but I forgot to post it promptly. This year's competition post is up now:
Winter Bash 2020 LEGO Prizes!
Please use that thread for any questions, discussion, or adjustments that may need to be made.

Considering the amount of bickering last year (see here), I hope that at least some of the proposed changes are applied if there are valuable prizes to be won (which inevitably attracts a crowd).
In short, if we could find a way to keep to the intended spirit of the competition (as outlined here):

The goal here is to facilitate positive engagement on the site both to celebrate the holidays and because this is the time of year when we get a lot of new traffic from parents and others just getting into LEGO. My hope is that providing prizes for this will facilitate meaningful engagement on the site. Please don't make a mess of things just to earn hats. :)

and here:

My hope is that Winter Bash can help increase engagement between current users and new users over the next several weeks by encouraging current users to be active on the site.

then I'm all for it, but I'm afraid it's a bit late to start discussing the best way now, as the hats are already being collected.
